# Zipfile module error: File is not a zip file

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
# File: zipfile-example-1.py

import zipfile,os,glob

file = zipfile.ZipFile("Apap.zip", "w")

# list filenames
for name in glob.glob("C:\Users/*"):
    print name
    file.write(name,os.path.basename(name),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
file = zipfile.ZipFile("Apap.zip", "r")
for info in file.infolist():
    print info.filename, info.date_time, info.file_size, info.compress_size
```

which produces this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/zip.py", line 11, in <module>
    file = zipfile.ZipFile("Apap.zip", "r")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 712, in __init__
    self._GetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 746, in _GetContents
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 761, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Anybody know why this error is occurring?

Comment: Rolled back the last edit because someone had edited out the entire question and replaced it with an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a

```
file.close()
```

after the first `for` loop.

Comment: Better Pythonic style to use `with` (context handler).

Answer (score 3):

Better style than explicit `file.close()` is to use `with`-style context handler (supported by zipfile since v2.7), making for much more elegant idiom, where you can't ever forget the implicit `close()`

By the way, don't ever name a local variable something like `file` which is likely to shadow globals and give very weird debugging behavior.

So, something like:

```
import zipfile,os,glob

with zipfile.ZipFile("Apap.zip", "w") as f:    
    for name in glob.glob("C:\Users/*"):
        print name
        f.write(name,os.path.basename(name),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
# `with` causes an implicit f.close() here due to its `exit()` clause

with zipfile.ZipFile("Apap.zip", "r") as f:
    for info in f.infolist():
        print info.filename, info.date_time, info.file_size, info.compress_size
```